# Retrieving data from database using js,php,ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to retrieve data from a database which is locally installed.
But the website is written and controlled with js, so I have to send an ajax request to a php-file, which then connects to the database, sends the query and later the result back to js.

I have a couple of files, because i followed this tutorial from 2012: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yb3c-HljFro

The structure:
|-ajax (Folder)
|   |-pkmn.php
|-db (Folder)
|   |-connect.php
|-js (Folder)
|   |-global.js
|-index.php

The files:
index.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
 </head>
 <body>
  Type: <input type="text" id="type"></input>
  Tier: <input type="text" id="tier"></input>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Suchen"></input>
  <div id="pkmn-data"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/global.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

global.js:

```html
$("#submit").click(function () {
 var type = $("type").val();
 $.ajax("ajax/pkmn.php", {type: type}, function(data) {
  alert(data);
 });
});
```

connect.php

```html
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root', '123456');
mysql_select_db('database');
```

pkmn.php:

```html
<?php
echo 'Hello';
```

The user should enter something into the text-inputs, then click submit and the global.js-file sends that text to the file pkmn.php via an ajax request.
But when I click the submit-button, I receive an error:

```
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Ungeschlossenes Token
Adresse: file:///C:/Users/Jonathan%20Frakes/Documents/testDB/ajax/pkmn.php
Zeile Nr. 1, Spalte 1:  pkmn.php:1:1
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Ungeschlossenes Token
Adresse: file:///C:/Users/Jonathan%20Frakes/Documents/testDB/index.php
Zeile Nr. 1, Spalte 1:  index.php:1:1
```

Which says something like:

```
XML-Parseerror: unclosed token
at: file:///C:/Users/Jonathan%20Frakes/Documents/testDB/ajax/pkmn.php
Row 1, Column 1: pkmn.php
XML-Parseerror: unclosed token
at: file:///C:/Users/Jonathan%20Frakes/Documents/testDB/ajax/index.php
Row 1, Column 1: index.php
```

I have absolutely no idea, what could cause this error.
Furthermore: When I close the php-tag in pkmn.php the console says BOTH errors moved to Row 3 Column 3 and when I close the php-tag one line later (by adding another newline) the error again moves in both files one down. I can also add spaces in front of the closing tag, moving the errors horizontally.

I have never seen something like this before, so please help me to fix that.

Best regards,
PanCave

EDIT:
changing the global.js according to this tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) now produces an "no root element found" error :/

```html
$("#submit").click(function () {
 var type = $("#type").val();
 var tier = $("#tier").val();
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("pkmn-data").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
 };
 xmlhttp.open("Get", "pkmn.php?type="+type+"&tier="+tier);
 xmlhttp.send();
});
```

Comment: I'd compare with another tutorial. Try this one with w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) It's not using jQuery ajax, but if it works without errors you have a better starting point.

Comment: I changed the javascript code (edit in orignial post), but now i get the error "No root element found"

Comment: _"XML-Parseerror: unclosed token
at: file:///C:/Users/Jonathan%20Frakes/Documents/testDB/ajax/pkmn.php"_ - PHP code does not get executed when you view files via the file system. You need to install a local web server and configure it to run such files through the PHP interpreter. WAMP/MAMP/XAMP are beginner-friendly packages.